# Optimizing Insert Calls in Java for bulk file uploads

Tags: spring, jpa, insert, bulk

deptcode|empname|jobtype|dept|doj

1. 121|John|Permanent|Accounts|12/12/2012
2. 122|Paul|Permanent|Revenue|11/12/2011
3. 123|Mark|Contractor|Sales|04/05/2010
4. 121|Mike|Permanent|Accounts|08/09/2009
5. 123|Nash|Contractor|Sales|12/15/2016
6. 124|Doe|Contractor|Marketing|12/04/2013

**Problem Description:**

1. That is the CSV file i am trying to upload using MultiFileupload.
2. Read it and create a list.
3. This list is validated against the EMP_TRANS_TABLE for duplicate
   records.
4. DEPT_CODE+JOB_TYPE+DOJ becomes my composite primary key.
5. I am using SPRING JPA Predicatesto check the duplicate values and
   then insert the values.
6. This is working fine till 750 records beyond that it is taking more
   than 4 mins to save the data and getting timeout to send the response back
       to front end.

**Technology Stack :**

1) Frontend- Angular JS

2) Spring Rest Services and Spring JPA(hibernate)

3) WAS 8.5 App server and SQL Server 2008 on Linux

4) Java 1.7

**Question**

1. How can i optimize my DB validations and insertion from java side
   as i cannot alter anything from DB side and cannot upgrade to Java
   1.8 also.
2. My requirement is to support 5000 records where in DB validation
   and Insertion should happen with in 2 mins.
3. Looking for optimal solution with relevant piece of code as it has to be applied for multiple web page uploads through out the application.

Answer (score 0):

There is hibernate property which you can define as one of the properties of hibernate's `SessionFactory`:

```
<property name="jdbc.batch_size">500</property>
```

With this batch setting you should have output like:

```
insert into Table(id , name) values (1, 'na1') , (2, 'na2') ,(3, 'na3')..
```

instead of

```
insert into Table(id , name) values (1, 'na1');
insert into Table(id , name) values (2, 'na2');
insert into Table(id , name) values (3, 'na3');
```

In a transactional method you would be persisting around 500 entities.. and then flushing your transaction for best performance until all of the data has been saved:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<5000; i++ ) {
    EmpTrans empTrans = new EmpTrans();

    // populate empTrans attributes

    session.save(empTrans);

    if ( i % 500 == 0 ) { //500 , same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
tx.commit();
```